# How to get the data of id in json using onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui

I'm using a axios to get my api to display some data from it. This works fine.
I want to get each of value and display the returned data when I click "TableRow"

this is my json data.
[image]

I want to get id and use axios api like this.

```
  const toDetails = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const getDetails = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`api/firstmemory/${id}`);
    setUserData(response.data.data);
     }
     getDetails();
    }
```

inside return

```
 return(
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>things</TableCell>
              <TableCell >date</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {userData.map((row,index) => (
              <TableRow key={index}>
                <TableCell>{row.first}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.date}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    );
```

Can anyone help me to figure this out ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `onClick`to handle the click on the row and `data-id` attribute to store the id value on the row.

```
<TableRow key={index} onClick={handleRowClick} data-id={row.id}>
   <TableCell>{row.first}</TableCell>
   <TableCell>{row.date}</TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

Then you can read the data-id attribute's value in the click handler with

```
function handleRowClick(e) {
   let id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id')
   // Your axios code here
}
```